# Dynamic URL rewriting with .htaccess - not rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to create seo-friendly URLs from my dynamic ones with a .htaccess rewrite. I've tried a ton of different rewrites and none of them are updating the URL. My other URL rewrite condition works fine...removing ".php" from the end of the URL.

Example:

Trying to change this:

```
food-truck.php?city=miami-fl&name=john doe
```

To this:

```
food-truck/city/miami-fl/name/john%20doe
```

Here is one of the rewrites I have tried with no success:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule food-truck/city/(.*)/name/(.*)/ food-truck.php?city=$1&name=$2
```

Any suggestions appreciated. Haven't been able to figure out a solution from similar questions in Stack Overflow posts or forums.

Thank you.

EDIT: Here is what did the trick...

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^city=([^&\s]+)&name=([^&\s]+)$
RewriteRule ^(?:food\.php|)$ /%1?/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^city=([^&\s]+)&name=([^&\s]+)$
RewriteRule ^(?:food\.php|)$ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\s\/]+)/?$ food.php?city=$1&rname=$2&r [L,QSA]
```

Comment: No error, the url just doesn't rewrite to anything. It just stays the same. Here is the url: www.example.com/food-truck.php?city=miami-fl&name=john doe

Comment: Apache Version 2.2.31

Comment: So you solved your problem?

Comment: Not completely...just made progress. Once I figure it out 100% and get it writing correctly, I will provide an answer to my question. I would still like to hear any input from people on why my original RewriteRule won't work.

Comment: Your original rule is fine but it is only rewriting pretty URL to original URL. It is not redirecting old URL to pretty URL

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra slash in the end of your rule. Try to remove it:

```
RewriteRule food-truck/city/(.*)/name/(.*) food-truck.php?city=$1&name=$2
```

Also maybe you need to add the beginning and end:

```
RewriteRule ^food-truck/city/(.*)/name/(.*)$ food-truck.php?city=$1&name=$2
```

Comment: Removed it - no luck

Comment: I improved it. check now

Comment: Still not doing the trick. Can't seem to figure out what is causing the issue.

Comment: which  url are you using to visit this page? is food-truck under domain root folder? Turn on rewrite log, you will see

Comment: Yea it's under the domain root folder. The url is this: www.example.com/food-truck.php?city=miami-fl&name=john doe

Comment: Found one that did the truck...but need to clean up the output a little bit. I put it at the bottom of my original question.

Comment: This is the output I get however: http://example.com/jacksonville?/professor%3f -> from the input -> http://example.com/food.php?city=jacksonville&name=professor